# Session gets reset when a post call comes to the page in webform application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, http-post, session-cookies, session-state

I have an ASP.Net 4.7 based webform application, requirement is at a certain page i need to submit form to a url(External Url) outside my application with some parameters, i need to send a return url (it will be the url of current page of my application), application running on that (External Url) will process data coming through the form, and redirects to return url,
Now the problem is when is receives that post call back in my application session of my application gets reset and all the data gets lost and i can see in context that session ID is different from one before, and because of my validations my application redirect it to login page.
Can anyone help why my session being regenerated.

these are my web.config settings.

```
    <sessionState 
  mode="InProc" 
  timeout="200" 
  cookieless="false" 
  cookieSameSite="Lax"
/>
```

This is how i am posting my data.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">", FormName));
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >", FormName, "POST", ExternalUrl));
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", "Var1", Var1));
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", "ReturnUrl", CurrentApplicationUrl));
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", "Var2", Var2));
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");

HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // 
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  After many days of trial and error I discovered a Certificate conflict between the localhost cert that IIS Express uses and the cert that my local IIS uses.  I had to remove the cert issued by RSA out of the "Personal"/"Certificates" folder and out of the "Trusted..."/"Certificates" folder in MMC (running as admin).  The code was fine. The conflict was that both certs were certifying "localhost".  Hope this helps.